# JS library to work with canvas

Tags: canvas, javascript

Do you know a good js library to work with canvas? I've already tried with Processing.js but i want to know if there are some good alternatives to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Burst Engine](http://hyper-metrix.com/#Burst) might be worth a look:

> The Burst Engine is an OpenSource vector animation engine for the HTML5 Canvas Element. Burst provides similar web functionality to Flash and contains a layer based animation system like After Effects. Burst uses a very light-weight JavaScript frame, meaning your animations will download un-noticeably quick and can be controlled using very simple JavaScript methods.

I think they're in the middle of a major rewrite though.

Comment: As far as I know, Burst is unfortunately no longer maintained. Take a look at [fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/test/demo)

Answer (score 2):

You should check out EaselJS. I've been playing around with it today and so far so good.

Answer (score 2):

[EaselJS](http://easeljs.com/) is the daddy. That combined with TweenJS and a decent sprite sheet generator will get you far.